# MySQL, Concatenate two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two columns in a MySQL table: `SUBJECT` and `YEAR`.

I want to generate an alphanumeric unique number which holds the concatenated data from SUBJECT and YEAR.

How can I do this?  Is it possible to use a simple operator like `+`?

Answer (score 228):

You can use the [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`SUBJECT`, ' ', `YEAR`) FROM `table`
```

Update:

To get that result you can try this:

```
SET @rn := 0;

SELECT CONCAT(`SUBJECT`,'-',`YEAR`,'-',LPAD(@rn := @rn+1,3,'0'))
FROM `table`
```

Comment: Your first answer, `SELECT CONCACT(SUBJECT, ' ', YEAR)` really helped me out. +1

Comment: The result is null when any row is empty on the fields to concat. What is the solution for that problem?

Comment: @TSR Good Question!  I found the answer for you.  If one of the fields happens to be null, you would need to use the MySQL IFNULL op.  So above would be like:
SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(`SUBJECT`,''),'-',IFNULL(`YEAR`,''),'-',LPAD(@rn := @rn+1,3,'0'))
FROM `table`

Answer (score 30):

You can use mysql built in CONCAT() for this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`name`, ' ', `email`) as password_email FROM `table`;
```

change field name as your requirement

then the result is

[image]

and if you want to concat same field using other field which same then

```
SELECT filed1 as category,filed2 as item, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(filed2 as CHAR)) as item_name FROM `table` group by filed1
```

then this is output
[image]

Comment: Nice. Just for your info, CONCAT used here is MySQL built in function, not a php function.

Answer (score 10):

In php, we have two option to concatenate table columns.

**First Option using Query**

In query, **CONCAT** keyword used to concatenate two columns

```
SELECT CONCAT(`SUBJECT`,'_', `YEAR`) AS subject_year FROM `table_name`;
```

**Second Option using symbol ( . )**

After fetch the data from database table, assign the values to variable, then using **( . ) Symbol** and concatenate the values

```
$subject = $row['SUBJECT'];
$year = $row['YEAR'];
$subject_year = $subject . "_" . $year;
```

Instead of underscore( _ ) , we will use the spaces, comma, letters,numbers..etc

Answer (score 3):

In query, `CONCAT_WS()` function.

This function not only add multiple string values and makes them a single string value. It also let you define separator ( ” “, ” ,  “, ” – “,” _ “, etc.).

Syntax –

```
CONCAT_WS( SEPERATOR, column1, column2, ... )
```

Example

```
SELECT 
topic, 
CONCAT_WS( " ", subject, year ) AS subject_year 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have two columns:
prenom and nom so to concatenate into a column with name chauffeur_sortant I used this script:**

```
SELECT date as depart, retour, duree_mission, duree_utilisation, difference, observation, concat( tb_chaufeur_sortant.prenom, ' ', tb_chaufeur_sortant.nom) as chauffeur_sortant, concat(tb_chaufeur_entrant.prenom, ' ', tb_chaufeur_entrant.nom) as chauffeur_entrant
FROM tb_passation 
    INNER JOIN tb_vehicule 
         ON tb_vehicule.id = tb_passation.id_vehicule
    INNER JOIN tb_chaufeur_sortant 
         ON tb_chaufeur_sortant.id = tb_passation.id_sortant
    INNER JOIN tb_chaufeur_entrant 
         ON tb_chaufeur_entrant.id = tb_passation.id_entrant WHERE tb_vehicule.id = '';
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid posting codes as images and post it as text instead. Because it will be hard to debug and cannot be copied to the code editor.

Answer (score -2):

```
$crud->set_relation('id','students','{first_name} {last_name}');
$crud->display_as('student_id','Students Name');
```