# Merging data from another table column into 1 seperated column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 3 tables (tbl_reservations / tbl_series / tbl_rooms), how can i return a with the matching rooms merged into 1 column separated by a space or a "|", along with data from the reservation table?

```
tbl_reservations
------------
id, startdate, enddate, series
1, 2014-05-20, 2014-05-22, 1
2, 2014-05-24, 2014-05-25, 2

tbl_series
--------
reservation, room
1, 1
1, 3
1, 4
2, 1
2, 2

tbl_rooms
-----
id, name
1, room a
2, room b
3, room c
4, room d
```

When i need returning is something like this...

```
startdate, enddate, rooms
2014-05-20, 2014-05-22, 1|3|4
2014-05-24, 2014-05-25, 1|2
```

Comment: Look at GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: If I understand what you mean properly then you need to Look into SQL Joins: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @MarkP Tsk, tsk, tsk http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource ;-)

Comment: @DavidG If you have some sort of application level interface, handle the display logic there instead

Comment: @Strawberry Oh deary me. I didnt know that. Apologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL, Concatenate two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346302/mysql-concatenate-two-columns)

Comment: Would it still be a concatenate... because its just 1 column but joining the data

Comment: Have now solved the issue using GROUP_CONCAT()

Answer (score 1):

as mentionned, use GROUP_CONCAT.
You don't seem to need tbl_rooms by the way...

```
select r.id, 
       r.startdate, 
       r.enddate, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.room order by s.room separator '|' ) as rooms
from tbl_reservations r
 join tbl_series s on s.reservation = r.series
group by r.id, r.startdate, r.enddate
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a8f3/9)

Comment: Used GROUP_CONCAT but in a different way and it's linking fine now.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to have all this in one column? in which case this is a duplicate:

[MySQL, Concatenate two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346302/mysql-concatenate-two-columns)

or

[MySQL combine two columns and add into a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-a-new-column)

or do you want to have a table after the query which will have each individual reservation in its own row. in which case you need to look at using the

```
INNER JOIN
```

functionality something like this:

```
Select * from tbl_rooms t1 
inner join 
(select * from tbl_reservations st1 
    inner join 
    (select * from tblseries) st2 
    on st1.id=st2.reservation
) t2 on t1.id = t2.room
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate as the point is to join multiple rows NOT separate columns. Solved the issue by using a GROUP_CONCAT().