# display as an array of array

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a school project, we have to make a web site which uses html/css and php/mysql.

I had no worries about html/css, but i have a problem with the mysql-part : i have a database Articles, with 3 cols (id, Message, id_member), i try to get only Message and id_member via `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Messages,id_membre FROM Articles") or die(mysql_error())`
and then `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` but this isn't what i really want to have..

i'd like to get an array of array which contains things like this :

`mess1 => id_member, Message;
mess2 => id_member2, Message2;
...`

Do you have any idea of how i can do that ? thx all, and wish you a good night from France !

Comment: You can use `CONCAT` function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346302/mysql-concatenate-two-columns

And you should use `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Your die statement needs fixing: `die(mysqli_error($con)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT Messages,id_membre FROM Articles"";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          var_dump($row);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

That will give you a traditional array you're looking for rather than an associative array.